# C# Draw method does not draw to screen after adding transformation matrix to spritebatch

Tags: c#, 2d, monogame

I have been trying my hand at making a simple 2D game in Monogame. I found a tutorial online for a Camera class to be used with scrolling the screen towards where my character is moving.

This is the camera class:

```
public class Camera
{
    Vector2 position;
    Matrix viewMatrix;

public Matrix ViewMatrix
{
    get { return viewMatrix; }
}

public int ScreenWidth
{
    get { return GraphicsDeviceManager.DefaultBackBufferWidth; }
}

public int ScreenHeight
{
    get { return GraphicsDeviceManager.DefaultBackBufferHeight; }
}

public void Update(Vector2 playerPosition)
{
    position.X = playerPosition.X - (ScreenWidth / 2);
    position.Y = playerPosition.Y - (ScreenHeight / 2);

    if(position.X <0)
    {
        position.X = 0;
    }
    if(position.Y <0)
    {
        position.Y = 0;
    }

    viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-position, 0));
}
```

And in the Game1.cs I use the following Draw method:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);


    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend,
    null, null, null, null, Camera.ViewMatrix);

    ScreenManager.Instance.Draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.End();


    base.Draw(gameTime);

}
```

When I use spriteBatch.Begin() without any arguments, the Titlescreen and mainmenu load just fine followed by the tilemap and the player.
However when I add the Camera.Viewmatrix argument the screen stays Black. It does not seem to draw anything past the Graphicsdevice.Clear(Color.Black).

I would appreciate any and all input. And please let me know if you need to see more of my code.

UPDATE:  The camera and matrix are fine I believe. The problem has to do with the fact that I have many classes, for example Screenmanager, Image, Tile, Layer, TitleScreen,... that are all using an Update  and most of them a Draw method.

The actual drawing is being handled as shown above in the game1.cs by a singleton instance of the ScreenManager class using its draw method.

I suspect that it is trying to apply the matrix to the fadescreen/titlescreen in the start and that is causing errors such as not progressing past the black background. Perhaps because the camera position has no player position?

I have tried using a separate spritebatch.Begin() for the Camera and Player draw methods but this of course results in the error that I'm calling a new spriteBatch.Begin before the other one has ended.

I feel like this is solvable but I might have been staring at it too long to see the solution now.

I don't want to turn this into a 'look at my entire project and fix it for me' but if anyone recognizes this situation and has input, or even has run into the same thing and fixed it, I would very much appreciate your feedback.

Also, should anyone require more code to look at, again. feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try feeding it an Identity matrix. That should work and it would confirm that something must be wrong with your matrix. It's been a while since I did this, but it think this worked.

```
 public void Update(Vector2 playerPosition)
 {
   if(position.X <0)
   {
       position.X = 0;
   }
   if(position.Y <0)
   {
       position.Y = 0;
   }

   viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-playerPosition.X, -playerPosition.Y, 0.0f));
}
```

Comment: Pardon my potential ignorance, but isn't what I do :
viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-position, 0));

essentially the same as your suggestion:
viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-playerPosition.X, -playerPosition.Y, 0.0f));

Comment: Yes, but you do the calculation at the top of the method, which is not included in my code. And please try the Identity matrix, if it doesn't, your matrix is correct.

Comment: Hi again, thank you for taking the time, really appreciate it! I tried to change it like you said but the result is the same unfortunately.

Comment: And that is with the matrix i suggensted, or with the Identity?

Comment: I hope Im understanding you correctly. I used the identity matrix in my draw function and the game loaded normally. spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend,
            null, null, null, null, Matrix.Identity);
 When I use the viewmatrix, the same problem comes back as before where the screen stays black.

Comment: Sorry! I must have missed the notification you replied! Anyways, if you haven't resolved the issue, it means that your `viewMatrix` is incorrect.